# values of ajax created input element become null when submitted

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a form like this. When I click on a class in the select drop down, fees are automatically populated for that particular class from mysql database.

```
    <form id="forma" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>" novalidate="novalidate">
                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="text1" class="control-label col-lg-4">Full Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                          <input type="text" id="text1" name="name" placeholder="fullname in block letter" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                      </div>

<div class="form-group">
       <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Admitted to Class:</label>
       <div class="col-lg-6">
       <select class="form-control" name="class_id" onclick="getFee(this.value)">
           <?php do {  ?>
           <option value="<?php echo $row_dep['class_id']?>"
             <?php if (!(strcmp($row_dep['class_name'], $row_dep['class_name']))) {
               echo "selected=\"selected\"";
               } ?>>
               <?php echo $row_dep['class_name']?></option>
                 <?php } while ($row_dep = mysql_fetch_assoc($dep));
               $rows = mysql_num_rows($dep);
               if($rows > 0) {
                 mysql_data_seek($dep, 0);
               $row_dep = mysql_fetch_assoc($dep);
               }  ?>
       </select>
     </div>
```

The following section is filled automatically with input boxes with their corresponding values from getfee.php when I select class.

```
<div class="form-group" id="sem">

</div>

<div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-5" for="dp1">Date of Admission
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>" data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd" id="dp2">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Session <?php echo date('Y');?></label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <select  class="form-control chzn-select" name="year">
                            <option selected value="<?php echo date('Y');?>">Session <?php echo date('Y');?></option>
                            <option value="2010">Session-2010</option>
                            <option value="2011">Session-2011</option>
                            <option value="2012">Session-2012</option>
                            <option value="2013">Session-2013</option>
                            <option value="2014">Session-2015</option>
                            <option value="2015">Session-2015</option>
                            <option value="2016">Session-2016</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Photo of Student</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                          <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                          <div class="fileinput-preview thumbnail" data-trigger="fileinput" title="image" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;"></div>
                            <div>
                              <span class="btn btn-default btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Upload Photo</span> <span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span> 
                                <input type="file" placeholder="Photo Upload" name="...">
                              </span> 
                              <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a> 
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="MM_insert" value="form1">
                       <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="col-lg-4">
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="submit">
                        </div>
                      </div>

                    </form>
```

The code works fine but when I hit submit button, the values of all input boxes from getfee.php disappear and become null.
Here is my getfee.php.

```
<?php 
require_once("configuration/config.php");
$class=intval($_GET['class']);
if (!$connection) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$query="SELECT * FROM admission_fee WHERE class_id='$class'";
$result=mysql_query($query);

?>

<?php while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Tuition Fee</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                 <input type="text" name="tuition"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['tution_fee']; ?>">
        </div> 
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Admission Fee</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="admission"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['admission']; ?>">
        </div> 
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Annual Fee</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="annual_fee"   class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['annual_fee']; ?>">
        </div>   
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Development Fee</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="development_fee"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['development_fee']; ?>">
        </div>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Saraswati Puja Fee</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="puja_fee"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['saraswati_puja_fee']; ?>">
        </div>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Identity Card Fee</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="id_fee"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['identity_card_fee']; ?>">
        </div>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Computer Fee</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="computer_fee"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['computer_fee']; ?>">
        </div>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Forms & Prospectus Fee</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="prospectus"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['forms_and_prospectus_fee']; ?>">
        </div>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">TC Charges</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="tc_charge"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['TC_charges']; ?>">
        </div>
    <label class="control-label col-lg-5">Other Charges</label>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
                <input type="text" name="other_charges"  class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['other_charges']; ?>">
        </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

And Javascript.js file is below

```
<script>

    function getVal() { 
        var xmlhttp=false;  
        try{
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        catch(e)  {   
          try{      
            xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
          catch(e){
            try{
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
            }
            catch(e1){
              xmlhttp=false;
            }
          }
        }

        return xmlhttp;
        }


    function getFee(class_id) {   

        var strURL="getFee.php?class="+class_id;
        var req = getVal();

        if (req) {

          req.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
              // only if "OK"
              if (req.status == 200) {            
                //document.getElementById('sem').innerHTML=req.responseText;
                req.responseText;
                var form=document.getElementById("forma");
                var d=document.createElement("div");
                form.appendChild(d);
                var div=document.getElementById("sem");
                div.innerHTML=req.responseText;

              } else {
                alert("There was a problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
              }
            }       
          }     
          req.open("GET", strURL, true);
          req.send(null);
        }   
      }

    </script>
```

Please help me. I don't know how to go on beyond this.

Comment: Where is the submit button? Where is the `<form>` that you're submitting? I just see a DIV.

Comment: @Barmar, Updated the question with submit button and form tag

Answer (score 0):

Timing. Reinit your dom on each change.
OR
if you are using jQuery just place your js inbetween:

$(function(){ // your code 
});

This snippet applies on each dom change, events and pageload afterwhile jquery present.

Comment: I am using a lot of jquery plugins. Do you think it's a js conflict? There is no error message in firebug that troubles me to detect where the problem might exist.

Comment: Well, thid means the debugger did not find any function or method than runs wrong or ended with error.

Comment: Anyway i have no other idea on this.